# Teradata MERGE with DELETE and INSERT - syntax?

Tags: merge, teradata

I have been trying to find the correct syntax for the following case (if it is possible?):

```
MERGE INTO TAB_A tgt
USING TAB_B src ON (src.F1 = tgt.F1 AND src.F2 = tgt.F2
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
ELSE INSERT (tgt.*) VALUES (src.*)
```

Background: the temp table contains a fix for the target table, as in it contains two types of rows:
the incorrect rows that are to be removed (they match with rows in the target table), and the 'corrected' row that should be inserted (it replaces all the 'delete' rows).

So essentially: remove anything that matches;
insert anything that does not match.

the current error I am getting is:

"Syntax error: expected something between the 'DELETE' keyword and the 'ELSE' keyword"

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Read the manual.  `WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (scr.*)`

Comment: Teradata does not support Delete & Insert simulatneouly in MERGE statement

Comment: @MatBailie did you? Because your statement doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of MultiStatement DELETE and INSERT statement to correct data from temp table into target table

```
DELETE FROM TAB_A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TAB_B WHERE TAB_A.F1 = TAB_B.F1 AND TAB_A.F2 = TAB_B.F2)
;INSERT INTO TAB_A SELECT * FROM TAB_B;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for not mentioning this, but I am looking for something that is transaction secure. However I guess I could use a begin/end transaction block, thanks

Comment: I think thats what your requirement was: 
Background: the temp table contains a fix for the target table, as in incorrect rows are to be removed and replaced by one correct row, from the temp table.

Comment: sorry my comment was not clear enough, i agree.. the merge statement shows what i want, just it is not possible. Updated the requirement..